# Change Comment Text Format in phpmyadmin

Tags: database

Hello i seem to hav changed the text format for my comments and now all my old comments cannot be seen. When i edit the comment the text format select list has no default value. I would like to give all my old comments the 'plain text' value. Thanks

Something that helped me sort the node body field was-

UPDATE `field_data_body` SET `body_format` = 'markdown'

Also i think it might be the  field_data_comment_body bit (plus revisions possibly) that need changed. Could anyone suggest anything for me?

Thanks

Comment: You already have the answer there...take a backup of your data, give it a whirl, and if it doesn't work _then_ come back here to ask for help :)

Comment: ah hah brilliant clive. You was right in that i was right, well almost right. This worked for me UPDATE `field_data_comment_body` SET `comment_body_format` = 'admincode' oh i better go see about revisions. You learn something new every day. Thanks