# Comment/Node Body Fields Not Applying Filters

Tags: input-formats

Hello ive been struggling for the past 24hrs getting my node body and comment body fields to use the text filters i have made. I wont go into the filter options just yet as the important thing here is that when i create a View html list with fields and Comment: Comment field, everything works well. I have paragraphs and my links convert so my text filters seem to be ok.

So i know its all to do with the Content Type's     comment_body    Long text   Text area (multiple rows) settings.

Filtered text (user selects text format) is checked. Text Fromat selected is my 'plaincustom' (originally plain text)

Web page addresses and e-mail addresses turn into links automatically.
Lines and paragraphs break automatically.

All seem to be available. When i view my node or comment though i just get it all in one big blob of text with no paragraphs or line converts.

Can anyone suggest anything that could help solve this issue? I do not know if this previous question i asked about changing text formats has any relevance to this issue. thinkign about it it might have. Then why does my view show ok?
[Change Comment Text Format in phpmyadmin](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/66257/change-comment-text-format-in-phpmyadmin)

Comment: i still cant get my head around why my html isnt showing paragraphs etc. I added a block here describign my woes and as you can see it displays the input filters ok http://www.onlinebanter.com/latest

Comment: even if i use full html as admin and us P tags about things it displays all in one line. It can only be to do with my content type field display. let me go back and see.

Comment: well i have managed to sort the node body field to work as expected. line breaks and converted urls. Just the body field now. Its using the same settings as the node body field. thats whats making it so strange for me.

Comment: ah hah my comment display was Plain Text. Simpel but...well im just glad i got there. Thanks.

Comment: If you found an answer yourself, it's good to post the answer below, and mark it as accepted so that everyone knows the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my comment display was Plain Text.